# Deploy a git tag to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an app on EB using the web interface (I switched to the UI approach, since by using the CLI utils: `eb int` + `eb start` I was unable to configure a postgres db because a mysql one is created automatically and by setting "postgres" in the config file I was getting an exception like "you can't change dbengine type"!!)
My problem is that currently I'm unable to use git to deploy my app, and I have to create and upload a zip file using the web UI (which is a process I really hate, since I'm in a very experimental state and I deploy very often).
If I try to use `git push.aws` I get:

```
./.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.rb:53:in `host': private method `split' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from ./.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.rb:112:in `signed_uri'
    from .git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push:86
```

…how can I use git to push and deploy a tag on my repository to EB in my current situation?

Comment: The error about engine type you were getting was due to a temporary Elastic Beanstalk bug which has since been fixed. Also you can specify db type and version in EB CLI 3.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `eb 2.6`:

Firstly, it's `git aws.push` (assuming you did `git aws.config` first). Alternatively, you can use the `eb` command (`eb init`, `eb branch`, `eb push`).

```
git checkout [tagname]
eb push # or git aws.push
```

For `EB 3.1`:

```
git checkout <tagname>
eb deploy <environment>
```

Also, AWS differentiates between Elastic Beanstalk CLI 2.6 and 3.1 by the former using lowercase `eb` and the latter using uppercase `EB`. At the command line they're still both run as `eb`.

Comment: So `git aws.push` is synonymous to `eb push`?

Comment: @TuukkaMustonen Yes. `eb push` is just a wrapper around git aws.push.